# Networking related blogs/wiki/forums to follow

Tags: untagged

What networking related blogs/wiki/forums do you find valuable to
read/follow/subscribe on a daily or regular basis?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the english one I follow (cisco tips oriented) :

- http://supportwiki.cisco.com/ViewWiki/index.php/Tech_Insights:Homepage great but missing a rss
- http://wiki.nil.com/Main_Page
- http://blog.ioshints.info/ a must have for cisco users
- http://blogs.nil.com/
- http://ciscogeek.org/ not often updated but have some nice post

Comment: @radius, you could have asked for Cisco blog and wiki references. Wait, I know -- Cisco IS networking :-)

Comment: Others than Cisco are welcomed. I don't have any blogs regarding general network news like "YYY is launching a new router" this is interestant at least to see what others are doing.

Comment: I was just kidding. There is one more updates place which incidentally also seems to have lots of Cisco updates. I added it to my list.

Answer (score 2):

Bear with me as I have some news sites along with my blog list.

- [NetworkWorld News](http://www.networkworld.com/news/) and specific columns
- [SecurityFocus](http://securityfocus.com)
- [DarkReading](http://darkreading.com/)
- [SANS Internet Storm Center](http://isc.sans.org/) page
- [SecLists](http://seclists.org/) -- Security Mailing list archives ([Insecure.org](http://insecure.org/))
- Blog: [Symantec Security Response](http://www.symantec.com/business/security_response/) weblog
- Blog: [The Last Watchdog](http://lastwatchdog.com/)
- [LightReading](http://www.lightreading.com)
- Also, [Slashdot IT](http://it.slashdot.org/) and [ConfickerC](http://www.confickerc.net/)
- [Multi-Link](http://www.mlcp.com/news/) communications products news page

Some less frequented places.

- Blog: [Securosis](http://securosis.com/blog/)
- Blog: [Sean Convery](http://www.seanconvery.com/weblog/)
- Blog: [The Invisible Things](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/)

And, Please don't tell me Security is not part of Networking.

Comment: Security is a big part of Networking. I totaly agree, that why I puted a +1 :)
Sean Convery also seems great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Renesys Blog](http://www.renesys.com/) - Blog keeping track of interesting behaviour/events in the internet.

[Cisco Blog](http://www.ciscoblog.com/)- Unofficial blog focusing on recent Cisco developments.

[Cisco IOS Hints & Tips](http://ioshints.blogspot.com/)

[PacketLife.net](http://www.packetlife.net) - Excellent site, with several very handy cheat sheets.

[PPC-1](http://www.pipeinternational.com/) - A blog chronicling an Australian project to commission a new undersea link. An excellent insight into how carriers work.

Answer (score 1):

Network Engineering is an "old" enough community that the good stuff is still mailing lists.  Specifically [cisco-nsp](http://puck.nether.net/mailman/listinfo/cisco-nsp) for cisco stuff and [nanog](http://www.merit.edu/mail.archives/nanog/) for internet/isp/bgp stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[Glen's Exchange Dev Blog](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/) is a great MS exchange blog.

Comment: This is more sysadmin related rather than network related

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Enterprise Networking Team](http://blogs.technet.com/networking/default.aspx) blog